# How to extract the parameter from Json Response Using Groovy in SoapUI?

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

the below is my response..

```
jsonCallback({"validationErrors":null,
              "response":{"type":"PreTokenResponse",
                          "preToken":"43a81ef8-693d-4e3d-ad83-f8ed76f39756",
                          "errors":null},
              "exception":null});
```

Now when I use

```
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("xxx").getPropertyValue("response")
```

The above script is extracting the response. Now I wanted to extract "preToken" value.

How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried:

```
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("xxx").getPropertyValue("response").preToken
```

Comment: Hi,
//Below is my groovy script
import groovy.json.*;
def responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Request 1").getPropertyValue("response")
log.info (responseContent)
//It was Printed as follows
jsonCallback({"validationErrors":null,"response":{"type":"PreTokenResponse","preToken":"43a81ef8-693d-4e3d-ad83-f8ed76f39756","errors":null},"exception":null});
//Now I want to print only the "preToken" value which is "43a81ef8-693d-4e3d-ad83-f8ed76f39756"
Could you please tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that your response instead of a pure *Json* object, has `jsonCallback()` string wrapping your *Json*.

So supposing that your response has this text, you've to remove it before parse the *Json* object, once it's remove it you can parse it using the `JsonSlurper` and access your `preToken` element using the correct path:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = '''jsonCallback({"validationErrors":null,
              "response":{"type":"PreTokenResponse",
                          "preToken":"43a81ef8-693d-4e3d-ad83-f8ed76f39756",
                          "errors":null},
              "exception":null});'''

// remove the unnecesary data               
response = response - 'jsonCallback('
response = response - ');'
// now you've a correct json
log.info response

// parse the json
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
// access the desired value
log.info json.response.preToken
assert '43a81ef8-693d-4e3d-ad83-f8ed76f39756' == json.response.preToken
```

I use your response as string only to give you a working example in *SOAPUI* it  must be the same, but getting the `response` from the property of your testStep:

```
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("xxx").getPropertyValue("response")
```